# mysql : display multiple results with heading

Tags: mysql

I'm a complete newb so forgive me.

I'm trying to get the results to display 2 or more different headings.

```
SELECT sum(fare) AS totalfare, count(*) AS fare10 
where fare>10
FROM tbl
```

I'm trying to get the `WHERE` statement apply to only `count`, not the `sum`, and have the result display as "`totalfare`" "`fare10`"

```
SELECT sum(fare) AS totalfare
FROM tbl
union
SELECT count(*) AS watever 
FROM tbl 
where fare > 10
```

I've tried this way, but the result grid would spit out the answers under 1 heading as totalfare. Is it possible to display it as `totalfare | whatever`?

Comment: `where` goes after `from`.  I consider this a typographical error and vote to close.

Comment: thank you all. you guys are great. i'm a complete new self-learner. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT sum(fare) AS totalfare,
       sum(case when fare > 10 then 1 else 0 end) as fare10
FROM tbl;
```

In MySQL you can also shorten this to:

```
SELECT sum(fare) AS totalfare,
       sum(fare > 10) as fare10
FROM tbl;
```

Comment: wow thank you. a follow up question is why does this statement sum(fare > 10) as fare10,  count the number of entries > 10,  instead of summing only the fare values > 10?

Comment: @groo . . . Because `fare > 10` is a boolean expression.  MySQL treats boolean expressions as integers in a numeric context, with 0 for false and 1 for true.

Comment: @groo . . . As the OP, you have the privilege of accepting any answer you like.  But anyone else who reads the question should be aware that this answer is better both in terms of being easier to write and in terms of have better performance (it only reads the table once and aggregates the results once).

Comment: actually i liked your answer too. i liked both really. it gave me as a noob a good start. if i could tick both i would :)

Answer (score 1):

Finally you explained your question. You can do UNION only when you have tables (result sets) with the same fields. This is what you need. The above query selects directly from the derived table created by the two sub-queries.

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    (SELECT 
        SUM(fare) AS totalfare
    FROM
        tbl) a,
    (SELECT 
        COUNT(*) AS watever
    FROM
        tbl
    WHERE
        fare > 10) b
```

You will get results as one row

```
[ totalfare | watever ]
   number      number
```